# Operator delete causing heap corruption while operator new working fine

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have got operator new working but as soon as I call delete, it crashes at the `free (ptr)` line. Can any one tell what I am doing wrong when overloading operator new and delete in this Base class? Hint: I am not asking about design issues.

```
class Base {
private: 
    int i;

public:  
    Base () : i (10) {
    }

    static void * operator new (size_t size) {  
       if (size = 0) size = 1;  // please read this line carefully! size = 0!
       return malloc (size);  
    }

    static void operator delete (void *ptr, size_t size) {
       if (ptr == NULL) return;
       free (ptr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete an object twice or delete an object via a pointer not obtained from calling `new`?

Comment: As a side note, `free(NULL)` is guaranteed to be safe (a no-op), so you don't have to special case it.

Comment: hm...My bad: if you replace `if (size==0)` with `if (size=0)` and add a private data member as well as a constructor, the code will fail. I know `size=0` is a bug which shouldn't happen but the code fails ONLY when you initialize a private data member of this class in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    void * operator new(size_t size) {
       if (size == 0) size = 1;
       return malloc (size);
    }

    void operator delete (void *ptr, size_t size) {
       if (ptr == NULL) return;
       free (ptr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Base;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
hank@tardis:/tmp$ g++ -o test test.cpp 
hank@tardis:/tmp$ ./test 
hank@tardis:/tmp$ valgrind ./test 
==7229== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7229==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7229==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1 bytes allocated
==7229== 
==7229== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7229== 
==7229== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7229== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your code is fine. I have done some further changes in my code. Can you comment on that?

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is with neither `new` nor `delete` operators. Your implementation of them is pretty straightforward, there's no problem here.

The actual problem you have as **heap corruption**. It's caused by your code, not necessarily the code that manipulates `Base` objects.
It's just the heap corruption gets discovered exactly when you `delete` your object.

Probably you have some code that does heap corruption just before you `delete` your object.

You should check your code for invalid memory access. This includes:

1. Ensuring you don't access more memory than allocated
2. Ensure you don't use memory after you free it.
3. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the sample code you have given.

The following works fine for me.

```
prasoon@prasoon-desktop ~ $ cat leak_check.cpp && g++ leak_check.cpp && valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
#include <cstdlib>
class Base {
public:
    static void * operator new (size_t size) {
       if (size == 0) size = 1;
       return malloc (size);
    }

    static void operator delete (void *ptr, size_t size) {
       if (ptr == NULL) return;
       free (ptr);
    }
};

int main()
{
   Base * p = (Base *) Base::operator new(sizeof(Base));
   Base::operator delete((void*)p,sizeof(Base));
}
==4561== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4561== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4561== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4561== Command: ./a.out
==4561== 
==4561== 
==4561== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4561==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4561==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1 bytes allocated
==4561== 
==4561== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4561== 
==4561== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4561== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 6)
```

BTW freeing a null pointer is perfectly fine.

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, **no action occurs**.

So `if (ptr == NULL) return;` can be omitted.